# CSS text-overflow: ellipsis; is working in Firefox but not working in drop down list in Google Chrome and Opera browsers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want to limit the length of text in options of a drop down list and for that the html and css style is as follows. It works perfectly fine in Firefox browser but  is not working in Google Chrome and Opera Browsers.

```
<div class="select">
 <select name="option[1381]" id="input-option1381" class="form-control ">
  <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
  <option value="5051" data-engraving="Checkered Clipboard Clip"> Checkered Clipboard Clip  (+$1.50)</option>
  <option value="5050" data-engraving="Blackout Clipboard Clip"> Blackout Clipboard Clip (+$1.50)</option>
 </select>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.select select {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

What could be the reason? I don't have any idea why it isn't working in opera and chrome. Please help.

Comment: You cannot (reliably) apply styles to `<select>` elements or their `<option>`s.

Comment: But it works in firefox, and sir please suggest me how to apply style reliably i am not an expert :)

Comment: `<select>` is a kind of "replaced element", it has special behaviour such as providing a list of options and a way for the user to select one. While this is fairly consistent on desktop (a drop-down box), mobile browsers or browsers with touchscreens may differ (eg. showing a pop-up box with the list of items having radio buttons to allow the user to select one). Since the behaviour itself is browser-specific, it's impossible to reliably set styles on it. If you want that, you would need to implement your own custom system, with support for mobile browsers too!

Comment: Ok i applied style on select because the text in it was overlapping with drop down arrow, what could be the possible solution for that?

Comment: Use a browser that doesn't suck? Here's how it looks in [Microsoft Edge](http://image.prntscr.com/image/afb260a52df147c69a50f60cc4360cd3.png) and [Google Chrome](http://image.prntscr.com/image/9ce7d070f4684cbbb6ee382a4e09f50e.png) (I uninstalled Firefox because it's crap...)

Comment: I need to make that thing compatible with every browser and i find out the solution, anyway thanks sir for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (reliably) apply text-overflow:ellipsis; to `<select>` elements or their `<option>`s. So, I had solved the issue by adding some extra padding-right. This way the text doesn't have an opportunity to run into arrow as it cannot enter the padded area. Problem solved !

```
<div class="select">
 <select name="option[1381]" id="input-option1381" class="form-control ">
  <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
  <option value="5051" data-engraving="Checkered Clipboard Clip"> Checkered Clipboard Clip  (+$1.50)</option>
  <option value="5050" data-engraving="Blackout Clipboard Clip"> Blackout Clipboard Clip (+$1.50)</option>
 </select>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.select select {
  padding-right:35px;
}
</style>
```